# Passing unconstrained generic type parameter to a constrained method

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have too methods:

```
public TValueType? DoStuffWithValueType<TValueType>(int x, int y) 
   where TValueType: struct {}

public TRefType DoStuffWithRefType<TRefType>(int x, int y) 
   where TRefType: class {}
```

How can i wrap them in a new third method?

The following is not compiling since i cannot persuade the compiler that `T` is in fact a struct when calling `DoStuffWithValueType`:

```
public T DoStuff<T>(int x, int y) {

   if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
   {
      return DoStuffWithValueType<T>(x, y);
   }

   return DoStuffWithRefType<T>(x, y);
}
```

I already tried overloading `DoStuff`, but this attempt failed since generic-constraints are not part of the method signature.
I also tried to get rid of the constraints, but i could not.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Just a warning in advance: the fact that a type is a value type does not necessarily mean that it is a valid generic type argument for a `struct` constraint. Nullable value types cannot be used with either `class` or `struct` constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, basically - you'd have to invoke the relevant methods with reflection, which is ugly.

Of course you can do this with dynamic typing, which hides the reflection from you:

```
public T DoStuff<T>(int x, int y) {
   dynamic d = this;
   if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
   {
       return d.DoStuffWithValueType<T>(x, y);
   }    
   return d.DoStuffWithRefType<T>(x, y);
}
```

You may think that's cleaner than doing it manually with reflection - or you may not :)

There's no way that I'm aware of to make the compiler "trust" a type argument where it wouldn't normally do so.

Comment: thank you! Never thought a celebraty like yourself would answer one of my questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from Jon Skeet's use of `dynamic`, the cleanest way I can think of, minimising the required reflection, and so keeping as much verified by the compiler as possible, is to call the method through a helper class.

```
abstract class DoStuffHelper<T> {
    public abstract T DoStuff(int x, int y);
}

class DoStuffWithValueTypeHelper<T> : DoStuffHelper<T> where T : struct {
    public override T DoStuff(int x, int y) {
        return DoStuffWithValueType<T>(x, y);
    }
}

class DoStuffWithRefTypeHelper<T> : DoStuffHelper<T> where T : class {
    public override T DoStuff(int x, int y) {
        return DoStuffWithRefType<T>(x, y);
    }
}

public T DoStuff<T>(int x, int y) {
   DoStuffHelper<T> helper;
   Type helperType;

   if(typeof(T).IsValueType)
       helperType = typeof(DoStuffWithValueTypeHelper<>);
   else
       helperType = typeof(DoStuffWithRefTypeHelper<>);

   helperType = helperType.MakeGenericType(typeof(T));
   helper = (DoStuffHelper<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(helperType);

   return helper.DoStuff(x, y);
}
```

If appropriate for your situation, you can cache the helper classes in a `Dictionary<Type, object>` to avoid re-creating them every time.